# How can I get the event to fire more than once.

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events

Thanks for input, my 1st attempt at this. I can only get the buttons to work once, I would like them to work every time as user will change search terms and results in different frame.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#button1").click(function(){
        $('form#myForm').attr({action: "completed.php"});
        $('form#myForm').attr({target: "righty"});
        $('form#myForm').submit();
    });

    $("#button2").click(function(){
        $('form#myForm').attr({action: "search.php"});
        $('form#myForm').attr({target: "lefty"});
        $('form#myForm').submit();
    });

    $("#button3").click(function(){
        $('form#myForm').attr({action: "amazonsearch.php"});
        $('form#myForm').attr({target: "righty"});
        $('form#myForm').submit();
    });


});
```

HTML:

```
<form id="myForm" method="post">
    <input name="Query" type="text" value="$title" size="60">
    <input type="button" id="button1" value="Completed" />
    <input type="button" id="button2" value="More Like" />
    <input type="button" id="button3" value="Amazon" />
</form>
```

Comment: You should consider moving away from frames. [Frames are evil.](http://www.html-faq.com/htmlframes/?framesareevil)

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to use

```
<form id=\"myForm\" method=\"post\"> just <form id="myForm" method="post">
```

that applies to all

Answer (score 0):

I made a [jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/daybarr/XB4v9/) (with slight tweaks to targets, names etc to get things to work in that environment) and it works for me in both Firefox 3.6 and Chrome. Click a button, form is submitted to target. Update the query, click same button again, the form is submitted to the same target again.

Comment: Thanks for demo, I was unaware of this site, it seems to be very useful for someone learning js like me. I still could not get it working until I added .live then everything OK. I appreciate your effort.

Comment: @Rick: So the jsfiddle demo doesn't work for you without `.live`? Which browser are you using?

Answer (score 0):

try using [.live](http://api.jquery.com/live/) instead

```
$("#myObject").live('click', function() {

    // do things
});
```

Comment: *Why* does this work? The jsfiddle demo given in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6865108/how-can-i-get-the-event-to-fire-more-than-once/6865461#6865461) works without it, so there must be something else going on.

Comment: With `click` it only works if the clickable element is present on page load.  With `live` it works anytime.